# pdftoppm font error while converting to png

Tags: poppler, pdftoppm, poppler-utils

I have a pdf which I am converting to image, when converted from pdf file the image has distorted font (attached image). But when I am extracting the page and the converting the image seems to be fine.

ORIGINAL_PDF.pdf -> pdf file

```
❯ pdffonts -f 5 -l 5 ORIGINAL_PDF.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Arial                                CID TrueType      Identity-H       no  no  no    8118  0
Helvetica-Bold                       Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no       3  0
Helvetica                            TrueType          WinAnsi          no  no  no       2  0
```

ORIGINAL_PDF_PAGE05.pdf -> PDF with just page 5

```
❯ pdffonts ORIGINAL_PDF_PAGE05.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
AAAAAB+Helvetica-Bold                TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no       6  0
AAAAAC+ArialMT                       TrueType          MacRoman         yes yes no       7  0
```

[[image: IMAGE GENERATED FROM PDF]]
[[image: IMAGE GENERATED SEPARATELY]]